# Should I write unit tests for unimpemented methods?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

We have created an interface for our repository classes that have common methods.  There is a scenario where a new repository created does not need to implement a method in the interface.

In this scenario, we have written the method in our repository class to throw `NotImplementedException`. Is it worth writing any Unit Tests for this method?  If Yes, is it better to use `ExpectedException` Attribute?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: You're the one deciding how important it is to write unit tests for your code. You should use a standard exception though: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html.

Comment: (Off-topic: If you know you're not going to implement a method, then throw `NotSupportedException`. If, however, you simply haven't yet got around to implementing a method, but you're planning to, then throw a `NotImplementedException`.)

Comment: I feel stakx answer is appropriate for my situation.  Should I write unit test for Notsupportedexception?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should write a test for that method, it shouldn't take very long if you're already testing other methods in the class.

Writing a test for it helps to document that it was a conscious decision not to implement the method, not just something that was forgotten.  It also acts as a reminder if in the future somebody comes along and implements the method that they need to write some tests for it.

As far as the `ExpectedException` attribute goes, it's very subjective.  I rarely use it, other people use it all the time.  You should use whatever approach is most common within the rest of your tests which are checking for exceptions.